# export the ad group details and member count to csv file

Tags: powershell

I have a script to collect AD group and member count in each group.
Can anyone help me to export the output in csv

```
$GroupArray = Get-ADGroup -Properties Modified, Members -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=oimstage,DC=corp,DC=com"
 Foreach($Group In $GroupArray)
 {
     Write-Host
     Write-Host "Group Name:"$Group.Name
     Write-Host "Total members:"($Group.Members).count
     Write-Host "Modified date:"$Group.modified
     Write-Host
 }
```

Comment: `$GroupArray | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: I only want groupname and number of member in each group. If I export the results from $grouparray it will only show grouname

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use a `custom PowerShell object` to export selective properties. Try this -

```
$GroupArray = @() 
Get-ADGroup -Properties Modified, Members -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=oimstage,DC=corp,DC=com" | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Group Name" $_.Name
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Total members" $_.Members.Count
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Modified date" $_.modified
    $GroupArray += $obj
}
```

You can add any number of properties to your custom object and store it in an array. Then you can export the array to a `csv` via `Export-Csv` cmdlet. You can modify `$obj` as per your requirements.

Comment: The csv results coming in ths format  "Administrators"?"4"

Comment: The above works well enough for me. What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Administrators,4